# Is there a way to change Bootstrap's theme colours at runtime?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, asp.net-bundling

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application for which I am planning to use Bootstrap (as it is part of the default MVC template). I understand that it is pretty trivial to customise bootstrap to look however I want, and how to override the theme colours by creating my own `site.scss` file that imports `bootstrap.scss` after defining overrides for the theme colors:

```
$theme-colors: (
    primary: #123456; // whatever colour I want here
);

@import "bootstrap.scss";
```

This is then compiled to `site.css` and served to our clients.

However, our clients need to be able to define their own theme. So if they want blue buttons they get blue buttons, if they want red, they get red. Is there any supported way of doing this with Bootstrap?

I have considered creating a finite set of coloured themes that they can choose from and having a separate `.scss` file for each of them, then serving the appropriate `.css` but I would like to make use of the ASP.NET bundling feature, and this is done at application start up so I would have to also have a separate bundle per theme option.

Also, I noticed that when you compile `boostrap.scss` you get a list of css variables:

```
:root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  ...
  --primary: #123456;
}
```

And briefly thought that it would make use of these when applying styles throughout, and that I could therefore override from a separate style sheet to set my custom colours. Sadly throughout the rest of the `.css` file hex codes are used rather than the corresponding css variables. To prove a point I did a find and replace for all the colours listed as css vars and I was able to override them from a subsequent style sheet essentially providing a theme at run time. But this isn't a great solution as it requires editing the compiled css file (which will get over-written frequently during development).

Does any one have any better ideas?

Comment: SASS is precompiled to CSS so there's really no way to re-compile SASS in the browser. You can expose SASS on a server via an API, and then call that API from JS in the browser.

Comment: You could have one stylesheet with the main styles (layout, font definition) and many stylesheets with the colors definition only. Then, change a class or even change the active stylesheet to change the interface colors. Or maybe let the client pick the theme, and compile the css in the server storing the result in a specific css for the client.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use JavaScript or jQuery. When a client changes colour assign that colour to variable and make change in css, using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: I don't think this is worth an answer and should be a comment